# libgnome-2.0 missing from 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04

After upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, gnome commander no longer works.

`gnome-commander: error while loading shared libraries: libgnomeui-2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I'm trying to install gnome commander from source, and it's complaining about

`No package 'libgnome-2.0' found`

There's no apt package for it, nothing, it went missing. I can't even seem to find the source code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code here:

- [gnome-commander](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/gnome-commander)
- [libgnomeui](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/libgnomeui)

Yeah, they are not included in 20.04 release repository.

Gnome-commander related BR was closed as [libgnome deprecation BR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-commander/-/issues/34) duplicate. I could find the moved page here [wiki.gnome.org - LibgnomeMustDie](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/LibgnomeMustDie) .

The upstream project is alive here: [gitlab.gnome.org - gnome-commander](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-commander/-/network/master) . It is only dropped at Debian level. Not sure if all GTK3 migration are complete but I saw some late related commits.

It is up to you, try build from upstream repository, build snap package with `core18`, (both require some knowledge) or just move on to some alternative if there is any.

Comment: I've hit a wall, dependencies of dependencies of libgnomeui contain multiarch-support, which I cannot find, all links to it 404.

Comment: @king4aday , Could you give me one example to verify ?

Comment: So apparently this is still an open issue with GCmd, [they knew 10 years ago this library will be deprecated.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-commander/-/issues/34)  
Unfortunately the deprecation reasons link no longer works, but at this point I don't want to rely on deprecated old and antiquated libraries.

Comment: @king4aday So gnome-commander BR was closed as libgnome deprecation BR duplicate. I could find the moved page here https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/LibgnomeMustDie . The upstream project is alive here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-commander/-/network/master . It is only dropped at Debian level. Not sure if all GTK3 migration are complete but I saw some late related commits. It is up to you, try build from upstream repository, build snap package with core18, (both require some knowledge) or just move on to some alternative if there is any.

Comment: Yeah I mean I guess if it's deprecated other distros will drop support for it sooner or later too... I already had the gitlab repo cloned, but even the latest commit on the master branch still has some dependencies related to it.

Comment: @king4aday Only libgnome is deprecated, not Gnome-commander. However, it seems it will take time to get fully migrated to GTK3 and be back to Debian/Ubuntu repository. I will give snap a try but no promises :).

Comment: Yeah I meant libgnome :)

Comment: @king4aday , even snap is more complicated than what I expected. GTK2 apps need to set many environment variables manually. The more troublesome is shared lib in sub directories or custom one. Also local configuration should patched/customized to snap read/write paths. I am still not too familiar with, I suspect snap still missing too many auto features, otherwise same as with debian pacakging, packager/maintainer has to be very familiar with target project building.

Answer (score 1):

Today I [released](https://gcmd.github.io/2020/06/19/Release-v1-10-3.html) a new version of Gnome Commander in which I removed the dependency of libgnome, libgnomeui and gnome-keyring-1. You could give it a try. But as far as I heard, *gnome-vfs* was also dropped in Ubuntu 20.04, so you probably won't be able to build GnomeCommander on that distro as it still depends on that library.

By the way, as discussed above already... if anyone here want's to help creating a snap or a flatpak package, you are more than welcome to jump in.

Comment: Holy cow this was a roller coaster. I had to install dependencies like 12 levels deep, mostly from the [gnome sources](https://download.gnome.org/sources/), but **now it works!!!**

I also had to compile gnome-vfs without openssl support, because with openssl the compile ran into an error.

Comment: OK I spoke too soon, one restart later, and gnome settings seem to have reset to the default. Now I did a system restore with Timeshift, so I'm back to square one, trying to figure out how to do these dependencies without futzing up my system settings. Wondering if I could do a conatiner approach for this app, but still being able to see the whole filesystem.

Comment: That sounds good, at least you could run it. Awesome!!! I would be interested if you solved the gnome settings issue. From which version did you update Gnome Commander? Do you see any output when you start it in the terminal? I do not use Ubuntu so I could not give it a try by now.