# Ubuntu 20.04 libgnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I need to run a .sh file. But, when I run it, it gives me an error

```
sh: 1: gnome-open: not found
```

Then, I realize I need to have gnome-open, but it is not installed in Ubuntu 20.04. How can I install it? As I research, I found out that it is related with libgnome2 but I do not know how to install it. There is a related question here [libgnome-2.0 missing from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232446/libgnome-2-0-missing-from-20-04). Thank you.

Comment: As the link to the other question says it is not supported in 20.04

Comment: But I need it. What can I do?

Comment: Does it work in 18.04 if so install that  gone is gone.

Comment: Edit Line 1 of the script to use a newer alternative. See [What can I use instead of gnome-open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68961/what-can-i-use-instead-of-gnome-open) for alternatives.

Comment: I learned something as well.

Comment: @user535733 I am going to try it in couple of hours, I will edit here. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is encrytped. There are lots of weird characters, I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create local wrapper:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xdg-open /usr/local/bin/gnome-open
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.